# How to store and respond with variables for API request

Tags: api, postman

I am attempting to create a dynamic responsive server which is able to:

1. read a request
2. store the token in an environment variable
3. use that environment variable in the response back to the source

I am unsure where to begin with this, I have had a look at some API tools such as PostMan and Insomnia but although I can set up a mock server which would receive the responses, the data I want to save is not being stored in the variable and thus is not being used in the response.

Some guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What language and platform you are using?
If you are using any of the major public cloud options, (AWS, Google, Azure), there are easy to deploy API Gateway Services that required minimal code to get started and supports environment variables.

If you are using a local development only,

1. then you can get started with ASP .NET Core Web API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
2. Then use environment variable:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1
   Or instead once you setup your API running locally, you can use Postman variables:
   https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am pretty flexible with the language, I just want to set up the environment to work and watch it function. That is why ii was thinking I could do it with an API tester.. am i wrong in assuming this? I know that Postman mock servers can receive data.. I just cannot store the values in a variable to then put them in a response back